# Is it possible to Deep link to Instant Apps (Android) from a third-party / trusted apps?

Tags: java, android, deep-linking, android-instant-apps

From my Instant Apps, I want to use a third-party / trusted app for authentication, this will lead the user to switch from Instant App to a third-party app where the user will authenticate himself and the third-party app should be able to deep-link / switch to Instant App once the authentication is successful.

The question here is whether it is possible for a third-party app to return back the user to the Instant App? If yes, how?

Appreciate anyone's prompt response/suggestion on this. Thank You :)